doctrine 2 to Doctrine 3 = HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD not available
I had this in doctrine 2 for my query builder
$query = $query->setHint(Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD, 1);

Since updating to doctrine 3 it does not work anymore. VSCODE does not find the parameter at all so I assume it has been removed ?
What is the equivalent in doctrine 3 ?

Partial Objects are removed in Doctrine 3.0

@craigh Thanks for the link however that is weird because it says it should still be available: The allowPartialObjects configuration option together with the Configuration#getAllowPartialObjects and Configuration#setAllowPartialObjects methods have been removed. The new behavior is as if the option were set to FALSE all the time, basically disallowing partial objects globally. However, you can still use the Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD query hint to force a query to return partial objects for optimization purposes.

you're reading from the upgrade to 2.0 part of the document which is superseded by the portion I linked (from 2.0 -> 3.0). Partial objects are removed.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/3.3/reference/partial-objects.html
